# Moq: Proper way to verify that a method was called just once with given parameters?

Tags: moq

To ensure that a method got executed just once with given parameters (and only with those parameters), I think I have to check it twice so like:

```
_fileHandlerMock.Verify(x => x.DeleteFile("file.txt"), Times.Once);
_fileHandlerMock.Verify(x => x.DeleteFile(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

Is there a better way to check, something like an "exclusive" option or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Moq`** library provides the method specifically for that purpose. It is `VerifyNoOtherCalls`, it is used in combination with the verifying and it will ensure that no other calls have been made except the (already) verified calls.

```
_fileHandlerMock.Verify(x => x.DeleteFile("file.txt"), Times.Once);
_fileHandlerMock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
```